# Dataflow: Sort elements on a PCollection

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-platform

I have to process a lot of events stored in Big query. For that I am planning to write a dataflow pipeline to fetch them, aggregate them, and write them in multiple aggregated datastore objects. One requisite that I have is that event should be processed in order. Is there a way to guarantee ordered data processing in dataflow?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want to process the entire BigQuery dataset sequentially (in one thread), record by record, basically using a stateful for loop, in order of increasing timestamp?

Comment: Echoing jkff -- do you need to sort all events in timestamp order, or would it be ok to divide them up based on some key (such as user ID) and only sort within each division? How big would these divisions be? Also, why do you need to process them in order? Many aggregations may be computed on out-of-order data, so if you could describe the computation it would help understand the problem.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. No, I don't need to run the whole dataset. I have daily partitioned tables and my idea is to run a daily Chron that triggers the pipeline. I would group the events by user id and I would only fetch the events in one day. Each user could receive around 15.000 events per day and yes, I need to process them in order as I need to operate on the difference of the value (delta) between two consecutive events. At the moment I am doing Fetch -> GroupByKey -> Sort iterables -> aggregate -> save. I was wondering if there is a better way of sorting the iterables. Thanks!

Comment: Any leads on this?